# how to update express to version 4

Tags: express

I just tried to update my version of express to `4.0.0`

I used `sudo npm install -g express` and I can see the newest version has already been installed on my laptop.

However, when I type `express -v`, the version is still `2.5.8`. How to change it to `4.0.0`?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to uninstall it instead and run the command `npm install -g express-generator`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Express has removed the bundled generator from the main project, to update the express generator use this command:

```
$ sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

Then when you'll do `express -V`:

```
$ 4.0.0
```

You might get an error like:

> Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/bin/express not in
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator

If you do, just uninstall the v3 express generator like:

```
$ sudo npm uninstall -g express
```

Then do the commands above again.

---

Something else seems wrong with your installation, force the deletion of express v3:

```
$ sudo rm -rf $(which express)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. After I used uninstall -g express to remove the express and install -g to install new version express and used install -g express-generator as you said. Every step works fine, however, when I input express -v. It shows 2.5.8 again.

Comment: @Heartless_m ... It should be first: `sudo npm uninstall -g express` to git rid of express v3. Try doing `express -V` it should not find the express command. then install it with `sudo npm install -g express-generator`

Comment: I'm sorry, I tired to uninstall express and express-generator both. For example, when I type sudo npm uninstall -g express, the result shows unbuild express@4.1.0. But then I type express -v, still can see 2.5.8 and I can also use express to make a new express app

Comment: @Heartless_m that is odd, it seems like it is somewhere else. see my updated answer.

Comment: Finally, I figure it out. I used "$ which express" to find there was a file called express in usr/bin/, and I remove this file then install express again, it works. Anyway, thank you for help.

Comment: @Heartless_m I was just about to update my post with that but SO suddenly went read-only lol